# Sphinx alternative without Rails

Tags: ruby, indexing, full-text-search, search-engine, sphinx

I need an indexing and searching gem like Sphinx but without needing Rails Any suggestions ? It has to run under Ruby 1.9.3 on a windows box. Tried Sphinx without rails but it needs MySql and a lot of configuration, diddn't succeed. Can you recommend something that uses a build in db or feature like Sqlite ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While certain plugins (like `thinking_sphinx`) are Rails-specific, Sphinx itself is just a search server, and you can use the client gem directly to index and search whatever you want; it need not be in ActiveRecord (which, incidentally, you could also use outside of Rails if you wished).

Another alternative is [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), which provides similar functionality to Sphinx, including a sophisticated search system (supporting stemming and lots of other nice things).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response.
I allready tried solr but could not get it to work with windows/ruby193. Do you have a hello world-like sample of using sphinx withour rails ?

Comment: You'd probably want to use the Riddle gem, which is what `thinking-sphinx` uses on the backend: http://freelancing-god.github.com/riddle/getting_started.html . Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to have a lot of introductory documentation available, and I haven't used it enough to be able to help with that; sorry.

Comment: i tried to use sphinx but have no MySql installed, tried it with odbc text-driver but no success, get errors when i start the indexer. Something that uses Sqlite would be great. I'l edit the question. I'll upvote you for your answer, thanks

Comment: Peter, you should try `xmlpipe` in Sphinx.

Answer (score 0):

Although Sphinx itself works regardless of whether you use Rails or not, if you're having difficulties with it, you can always try something like [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or [Elastic Search](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch). I heard good things about the latter and it is quite trivial to get to run on Windows, as you seem to be.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative for sphinx,solr is [OpenSearchServer](http://www.open-search-server.com/) . A search engine based on lucene. And it has a good windows support. Have a look at the documentation here [how to install in windows](http://www.open-search-server.com/documentation/index.php/User_guide_-_Running_OpenSearchServer_on_Windows).You can use the API to integrate in Ruby.